# If $f$ is a increasing function in $[a,b]$, then is it true that $\text{Img}(f) = [f(a),f(b)]$?

Tags: functions

If $f$ is a increasing function in $[a,b]$, then is it true that $\text{Img}(f) = [f(a),f(b)]$?

I am in doubt because my book said no.

Is my proof correct?

> If $f$ is a increasing function, $$\forall x\in [a,b] : \,\, a \leq x \leq b \Longrightarrow f(a) \leq f(x) \leq f(b) \Longleftrightarrow \text{Img}(f) = [f(a),f(b)] .$$

Comment: Is the function continuous? (think of $f(x) = 1$ when $x\in [a, b)$ and $f(b)  =2$)

Comment: It said nothing about it

Comment: Ok, then it is only valid to continuous functions

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, yes.

Answer (score 3):

No, this only shows that
$$
\text{Im}f \subseteq [f(a),f(b)]
$$
If $f$ is not continous, this does not hold.

Say $f:[0,2]\rightarrow \mathbb R$, $f(x)=x$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(x)=x+1$ for $x \in (1,2]$

Comment: It's crazy how we came up with the same exact counterexample at the same time.

Comment: Not quite - I prefer left continous functions :-)

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, consider the function $f: [0, 2] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 0$ for $x \leq 1$ and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise.

If we assume $f$ is continuous, however, then the claim is true: Since $f$ is increasing, $\text{im } f \subset [f(a), f(b)]$ and by construction $\text{im } f \ni f(a), f(b)$. On the other hand, continuous maps preserve connectedness, so $\text{\im f}$ is a connected subset of $[f(a), f(b)]$ that contains $f(a), f(b)$, and the only such subset is $[f(a), f(b)]$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

False. You need continuity as well. Define $f(x)$ on $[0,2]$ by $$f(x)= \begin{cases} x \text{ for } x \in [0,1)\\ 
x+1 \text{ for } x\in [1,2] \end{cases}$$ 
for a counterexample.